# Why I receive a message from the Program Compatibility Assistant?

Tags: windows-vista, installation, launch4j

The setup of my own program produce after finish a message from the "Program Compatibility Assistant" that the program was not installed correctly but it is all correctly.

The same problem I have with the uninstaller. The problems occur under Vista. I use launch4j.

Why occur this message? How can I eliminate this message that my customer does not see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occur if you does not change any in the registry and/or the directory "program files". To solve this you need to do some changes on the system. Or you add a manifest to your setup.exe like described in [Program Compatibility Assistant thinks my app is an installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577412/program-compatibility-assistant-thinks-my-app-is-an-installer/2160444#2160444). See also at [How do I prevent programmatically the “Program Compatibility Assistant” in Vista (and Windows 7) from appearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587962/how-do-i-prevent-programmatically-the-program-compatibility-assistant-in-vista)