# Program Compatibility Assistant Manifest Not working in Vista32

Tags: winapi, windows-vista, manifest, compatibility, uac

When I run my application "A driver Installer and Uninstaller Application", I am getting a "Program Compatibility Assistant" window once my exe get ended successfully. After going through the SO links and googling I couldnt find a solution to avoid "Program Compatibility Assistant" window in vista 32. I used the below manifest to avoid PCA and it works as expected (am not getting any PCA window in windows 7) but except windows vista 32? What should I do to make this work?

> After Using the below manifest for my installer application I am not
>   getting PCA window in windows 7 but it appears on windows vista
>   32-bit. How to avoid PCA window in vista32?

Some related questions are:

- [how-do-i-prevent-programmatically-the-program-compatibility-assistant-in-vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587962/how-do-i-prevent-programmatically-the-program-compatibility-assistant-in-vista)
- [reasons-for-getting-the-program-compatibility-assistant-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098747/reasons-for-getting-the-program-compatibility-assistant-dialog)

Here's the manifest I used:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="Unins.exe"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

The below is the snapshot of PCA window I get...

[image: Snap Shot of PCA window]

Update : the root cause I for the PCA window is "My Installer is not creating an entry in Add or Remove Programs". I made my app to make an entry in "Add or remove programs" and am not getting any PCA window. But I dont want to make an entry in Add or Remove Program.

> **Update 25-09-12:** I have an executable say `A.exe`, which finds
>   architecture of the OS and depends on the architecture it calls either
>   `A64.exe or A86.exe`. In this case do I want to have manifests for all
>   the exe's ( A.exe, A64.exe, A86.exe )? Right now I have manifest only for A.exe.

Comment: @Deanna I have edited. To be short the above mentioned Manifest for my app doesnt display PCA window in windows 7 but it appears in Vista32 bit?

Comment: @Deanna any Idea on this or still wanna improve my question?

Comment: I don't have an answer at this time.

Comment: @Deanna Shall I set a bounty to draw more attention?? Am really stuck in this...

Comment: If you want to, that's what the bounty is for.

Comment: The `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1` namespace seems to be the default but repeated as `asmv1`. You could try tidying them up a bit?

Comment: @Deanna I couldnt get you Deanna... Can you please elaborate...

Comment: @Deanna r u asking me to remove this part xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" ??\

Comment: @Deanna I tried it out... Same response....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to opt out of PCA altogether, you will defintely need to include a manifest in all three of your executables.

Comment: Comments from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583006/manifest-for-an-exe/12583052#12583052

Comment: I don't know enough about exactly what is triggering PCA for you, and why precisely it only happens on Vista 32, for you. However, I do know that the `supportedOS` manifest section opts out of PCA, and also that manifests are not inherited by newly created processes. I think that's enough. I don't want to write in an answer the rather vague comments at the other question. I don't have the full details to explain why your original version behaved exactly as it did, but I do know the solution to the problem.