# Manifest for an exe?

Tags: windows, winapi, manifest, uac

I have an executable say A.exe, which finds architecture of the OS and depends on the architecture it calls either A64.exe or A86.exe. In this case do I want to have manifests for all the exe's ( A.exe, A64.exe, A86.exe )? Right now I have manifest only for A.exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, each module needs its own manifest.

In your case, if you were to start `A64.exe` from `A.exe`, and `A64.exe` does not have a manifest, then `A64` will run virtualized, it will not have access to comctl32 v6 and so on. A process does not inherit its manifest from the process that creates it, each process must supply its own manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. This might be the solution for the below mentioned post? please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532308/program-compatibility-assistant-manifest-not-working-in-vista32#comment16922120_12532308 But here I get PCA window only in Windows Vista 32 bit alone and in windows 7 it works fine...

Comment: Adding manifests to all your executables could well solve that problem. PCA will differ between 32 and 64 bit for sure, and also between Vista and 7, so the fact that you only suffer on Vista 32 bit is quite plausible. No matter what, you need to add manifests to your executables, so do that first, and see if it helps the other problem.

Comment: Thanks David.Yeah I did that. I made a seperate manifest for all the executables and noow I didnt get a PCA window in Vista 32 too. But I am bit confused why I didnt get a PCA in Windows 7 with same scenario..

Comment: Dunno. PCA just differs on different versions of the OS. Your exe was eligible for PCA dialog, but PCA obviously decided not to show it. Now you have excluded PCA and it's cannot show. Does my answer successfully answer your question?